# React child component prop updates are acting inconsistent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a loading bar component for a React app.

The percent gets passed in as an integer, but instead of transitionally updating 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc... 100, the prop is just updating 0... then straight to 100.

But this is where things get weird.

In the component's `render()` function, I'm outputting the percent with a `console.log()`, and the console shows the value updating transitionally (0, 1, 2, 3, etc... 100), but rendering it via `{percent}` still just holds at 0, then jumps straight to 100.

Also watching the React dev tools for the component shows it jumping from 0 to 100, but the `console.log()` in the render goes through all the numbers.

Here's the code for the component:

```
const Loader = ({msg, percent = null, inline = false}) => (
  <div className={"loader"+(inline ? ' inline': '')}>
    <i className="fa fa-refresh" />
    <span>{msg}</span>
    {
      console.log(percent+"%") // <- this updates number by number
    }
    {
      !isNaN(percent)
      ? <div className="progress-bar">
          <div style={{ width: percent+"%" }} /> {/* <- this jumps from 0 right to 100 */}
        </div>
      : null
    }
  </div>
);
```

Has anyone experienced anything like this before?

I've tried both a functional component and a class based component, but in both cases the `console.log()` updates correctly but the rendered value and the React dev tools value doesn't.

Parent component:

```
class ReadStory extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // ...

      renderTestStr: "",
      storyPages: [],
      pageHeight: 0,
      wordCount: 0,
      wordsRendered: 0
    };

    this.renderTest = React.createRef();

    this.paginate = this.paginate.bind(this);
    this.addWordAndCheckHeight = this.addWordAndCheckHeight.bind(this);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    // ...

    await this.paginate(storyData);

    this.setState({
      // ...
      loading: false
    });
  }

  paginate(storyData) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const {html} = storyData;
      const words = html.split(' ');
      
      const ps = window.getComputedStyle(this.renderTest.current);
      const paddingY = parseFloat(ps.paddingTop) + parseFloat(ps.paddingBottom);


      this.setState({
        pageHeight: (this.renderTest.current.clientHeight - paddingY),
        wordCount: words.length
      }, async () => {

        for (let i in words) {
          const isLastWord = (parseInt(i) === (words.length - 1));
          await this.addWordAndCheckHeight(words[i], isLastWord, i);
        }

        const {storyPages, renderTestStr} = this.state;

        console.log(storyPages);

        resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  addWordAndCheckHeight(word, isLast, i) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let {renderTestStr, storyPages, pageHeight} = this.state;
      const renderTestReset = renderTestStr;

      renderTestStr += (" " + word);
      this.setState({ renderTestStr, wordsRendered: (parseInt(i) + 1) }, () => {
        const ps = window.getComputedStyle(this.renderTest.current);
        const paddingY = parseFloat(ps.paddingTop) + parseFloat(ps.paddingBottom);
        const rtHeight = (this.renderTest.current.clientHeight - paddingY);

        if (rtHeight === pageHeight && !isLast) {
          resolve();
        }
        else if (isLast) {
          storyPages = [
            ...storyPages,
            renderTestStr
          ];
          renderTestStr = "";
          this.setState({
            storyPages,
            renderTestStr
          }, resolve);
        }
        else {
          storyPages = [
            ...storyPages,
            renderTestReset
          ];
          renderTestStr = word;
          this.setState({
            storyPages,
            renderTestStr
          }, resolve);
        }
      });

    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      // ...
      loading,

      renderTestStr,
      storyPages,
      wordCount,
      wordsRendered
    } = this.state;

    const renderPercent = !isNaN(Math.floor(wordsRendered / wordCount * 100))
      ? Math.floor(wordsRendered / wordCount * 100)
      : 0;
    
    console.log(renderPercent);
    
    let lrPages = [];

    for (let i in storyPages) {
      const isEven = (parseInt(i) % 2 === 0);
      if (isEven) {
        const lr = {
          l: storyPages[i],
          r: (storyPages[parseInt(i) + 1] || null)
        };

        lrPages.push(lr);
      }
    }

    return loading
    ? (
        <Fragment>
          <Loader msg="Loading story..." percent={renderPercent} />

          <div className="view read-story">
            <article className="book-page render-test">
              <div ref={this.renderTest}>
                <p>{renderTestStr}</p>
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      )
    : (
        <Fragment>
          {/* ... */}
        </Fragment>
      );
  }
}

export default withRouter(ReadStory);
```

It's a big view component, so I omitted a lot of code not related to the `Loader` component. The `paginate` and `addWordAndCheckHeight` functions probably look quite strange, but basically I have text I need to fit into variable height `<div>`s (pages in a book), so I need to add each word and re-measure the height of the `<div>` to see if it exceeds the height limit, at which point it breaks to a new page. As this process can take some time on larger stories, I'm trying to show a progress bar.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what how percent is incremented and if you get the log same behavior inside the `!isNaN` block. Also, `!isNaN(null)` resolves to true, so I don't think it's going to work the way you want.

Comment: How is `percent` updated, can you show the code?

Comment: It's a little complicated how it's being incremented, but I know it's being incremented correctly, as console logs from the parent component's `render()` function show the number increasing correctly too. I'll add the code anyways though. And good to know about `isNaN`, thanks @DCTID

Comment: I think the problem might be that updates are batched, and your loop is too tight, so there's not enough time for changes to render, maybe. Try adding a delay, it might work.

Comment: Hmm ok, I'll look into it and post if I get it working. Thanks @CertainPerformance

Comment: @CertainPerformance hey thanks, that did solve it. Adding a 1ms delay to each resolve prevents it from batching. Does mean the "loading" time will be slower, but at least it works and shows the bar incrementing properly. Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tight loop here:

```
for (let i in words) {
  const isLastWord = (parseInt(i) === (words.length - 1));
  await this.addWordAndCheckHeight(words[i], isLastWord, i);
}
```

because `addWordAndCheckHeight` doesn't necessarily wait for the changed state (and the updated `wordsRendered`) to be fully rendered before resolving.

You can add a slight delay inside the loop:

```
for (let i in words) {
  const isLastWord = (parseInt(i) === (words.length - 1));
  await this.addWordAndCheckHeight(words[i], isLastWord, i);
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10));
}
```

You could also wait to do the next iteration until after the next `componentDidUpdate` fires, to ensure it's been painted to the DOM and the user can see it, but that'll make the code a bit ugly.

Answer (score -1):

percent prop must be passed as a state value or a hook return value(in case you use function components) from parent component. As example you can look at [this codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-architecture-414vf?file=/src/App.js)